# How sort column values by number in string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

**Problem**: For each column I have in the dataframe, I have the structure number + "." + value(string). I'm trying to sort each column by the number but it's not working.
**Output**

```
Row1: Column1: 1.Test, Column2: 1.Test, Column3: 2.Test
Row2: Column1: 3.Test, Column2: 2.Test, Column3: 1.Test
Row3: Column1: 2.Test, Column2: 3.Test, Column3: 3.Test
```

**Objective**: Sort each column by the number that accompanies the string so that I can get the correct data for each row and not mixed up.

```
Row1: Column1: 1.Test, Column2: 1.Test, Column3: 1.Test
Row2: Column1: 2.Test, Column2: 2.Test, Column3: 2.Test
Row3: Column1: 3.Test, Column2: 3.Test, Column3: 3.Test
```

```
dfPrincipal.sort_values(by=list(dfPrincipal.columns),axis=0, ascending=False)
```

Comment: Could you post a reproducible input generating a pandas dataframe?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are asking @ivanp

Comment: This probably explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What @ivanp tries to explain is that it would be best to convert the data in your post, directly to a DataFrame, because the way you have written it so far, does not help very much in understanding the problem

Comment: See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] to provide the input and output in a format we can reproduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
pd.concat([df[x].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True) for x in df.columns], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     col1     col2     col3
0  1.Test   1.Test   1.Test
1  2.Test   2.Test   2.Test
2  3.Test   3.Test   3.Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sorter = lambda x: x.str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)

df.apply(lambda s: s.sort_values(key=sorter).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
        0       1       2
0  1.Test  1.Test  1.Test
1  2.Test  2.Test  2.Test
2  3.Test  3.Test  3.Test
```